# Failed to create solr core in Solr 8.9.0 using Solr API

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper, solrj

I have created Solr war file followed process as mentioned in
https://gist.github.com/fschiettecatte/836d13be0c95f1fd159e45d3af861952
as I want to run Solr as standalone application through my specific
version of jetty server.

## After creating war file I started solr through jetty successfully by

running below command:

```
$ java -Djetty.home=/var/solr -Djetty.base=/var/solr
-Dsolr.solr.home=/var/solr/solr -Dsolr.log.dir=/var/solr/solr
-Dbootstrap_confdir=/var/solr/solr/conf -Dcollection.configName=conf
-DzkRun -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/solr/solr/solr-log.properties
-jar /var/solr/start.jar

2021-08-20 07:49:40.869:INFO::main: Logging initialized @155ms to
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2021-08-20 07:49:41.021:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.18.v20190429;
built: 2019-05-10T18:03:12.512Z; git:
7ef7435fd940d3eb73c256b765d93aff5849c6e8; jvm 11.0.5+10
2021-08-20 07:49:41.029:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main:
Deployment monitor [file:///data/git/runtime/solr/webapps/] at
interval 1
2021-08-20 07:49:41.568:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO
JSP Support for /solr, did not find
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2021-08-20 07:49:41.572:INFO:oejs.session:main:
DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2021-08-20 07:49:41.573:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger
set, using defaults
2021-08-20 07:49:41.573:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2021-08-20 07:49:41.575:WARN:oejs.SecurityHandler:main:
ServletContext@o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@294425a7{solr,/solr,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8983-solr.war-_solr-any-17126331786779836602.dir/webapp/,STARTING}{/solr.war}
has uncovered http methods for path: /
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default
configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user
programmatically provided configurations. Set system property
'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for
instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
2021-08-20 07:49:43.647:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started
o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@294425a7{solr,/solr,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8983-solr.war-_solr-any-17126331786779836602.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/solr.war}
2021-08-20 07:49:43.652:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started
ServerConnector@6da9dc6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8983}
2021-08-20 07:49:43.653:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @2939ms
```

## My solr is working just fine I run few command to verify:

$ curl "http://0.0.0.0:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=clusterstatus&wt=xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">19</int>
</lst>
<lst name="cluster">
  <lst name="collections"/>
  <arr name="live_nodes">
    <str>192.168.1.2:8983_solr</str>
  </arr>
</lst>
</response>
```

## When I tried to create core it was failing with below error, before

running this command I created folder name “a10” under solr home
directory “/var/solr/solr/cores”

$ curl "http://0.0.0.0:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=a10&instanceDir=cores/a10&shard=shard10&collection=conf1&coreNodeName=a10&wt=xml"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
 <int name="status">400</int>
 <int name="QTime">10067</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
 <lst name="metadata">
<str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
<str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController$NotInClusterStateException</str>
 </lst>
 <str name="msg">Error CREATEing SolrCore 'a10': coreNodeName a10 does
not exist in shard shard10, ignore the exception if the replica was
deleted</str>
 <int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

## Backtrace because of this error in jetty console:

07:54:36.047 [qtp466505482-21] ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase - org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'a1': coreNodeName a1 does not exist in shard shard1, ignore the exception if the replica was deleted
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:1136)
at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.lambda$static$0(CoreAdminOperation.java:92)
at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.execute(CoreAdminOperation.java:360)
at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler$CallInfo.call(CoreAdminHandler.java:396)
at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:180)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:758)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:739)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:511)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:395)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:341)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:724)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:830)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController$NotInClusterStateException: coreNodeName a1 does not exist in shard shard1, ignore the exception if the replica was deleted
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1874)
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1773)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1180)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:1097)
... 41 more

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved when I started Solr in stand alone mode. I started solr in cloud mode because of that create core command was failing.

Solr API should be used only when solr started in standalone mode and Collection related API should be sued when solr started in cloud mode.